# Programmatically set chart to 'view mode' in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-visualization

Does anyone know if there is anyway to set an Embedded chart created via GAS to render in 'view mode' instead of 'edit mode'?

I scoured the docs, and couldn't find anything.  I saw this was asked once before as well, with no answer, so maybe it isn't possible (I don't have enough rep to comment, otherwise I would have tried to revive this question):

[Programmatically change to view mode for google embedded chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27922866/programmatically-change-to-view-mode-for-google-embedded-chart?newreg=d064b153e21e4a789d1124626449e105)

I'm using the [Embedded charts](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/embedded-chart), below is a simple example of how I'm creating them:

```
var chart = sheet.newChart().asPieChart()
  .setTitle("My Chart")
  .addRange(range)  
  .setOption("pieHole", "0.4")
  .setOption("width", 480)
  .setOption("height", 300)
  .build();

sheet.insertChart(chart);
```

The reference to "Edit Mode" is referring to the toggle button set circled in red in [this image](http://puu.sh/jYNMP/e511061b33.png).  The top button is "View Mode" (the eye), and the bottom button is "Edit Mode" (pencil).  The problem with edit mode is that you don't get the pop-ups for the data.

This is only on the initial creation.  If I create them, manually change them to "View Mode" and then 'modify()' the charts, they seem to remain in "View Mode".  It's a bit of a hassle though as there are a fair amount of charts.  And every time someone uses it for the first time, they would have to do this, so I'm just trying to see if it can be avoided.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How are you creating your chart? Is "edit mode" referring to the `ChartEditor` dialog? You can close that with [`closedDialog()`](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#methods_5).

Comment: @Andy, I updated the question to hopefully address the missing info.

Comment: @ThomEllis Did you ever find a solution for this?